# Facebook API Getting Spouse Name

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions

Thank you all for your support around here.

Me again and with a simple question, does anyone know how to get the Spouse/Partner/Fiancée name of the logged in Facebook user?

I am using the user_relationships permission and I get if the user is married etc... but I can't figure it out with who? I need the name of the person...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only get data of users who authorized your App too, so in order to get the name of your spouse, your spouse would need to authorize the App.

After that, you can use the `family` endpoint: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/family

Comment: Yes that is correct, upon agreeing and authorizing my app only then I have access. With the family API I am able to see the Family, but I don't know how to specifically call wife/husband name.

Comment: I don't know the wife or husband will need to also approve access? As long as one person allows, it's possible to read the spouse name, nothing else. Infact, I can even see their FBID which I can pull their photo... but this is all in the sandbox, I am stuck in getting exactly that query... oh man..

Comment: check out the "relationship" field of the family endpoint: /me/family?fields=relationship

Comment: either way, your wife or husband both need to authorize your app, that´s how it is. you can´t get the name of your spouse just because your authorized the app.